# What champions are good to support Kalista and how do they need to be played?

Tags: league-of-legends

I main support, but I'm not able to play Kalista until she's free.

What champions are good to support Kalista and how should you play/build them?

I'm asking this Question, because [Kalista has very unique mechanics](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kalista):

> THE BLACK SPEAR - ACTIVE: Kalista offers a pact to an allied champion. Should they agree, the item is consumed and binds them together, turning the target into a Oathsworn ally for the remainder of the game. Kalista requires an Oathsworn ally to utilize  Sentinel's, Soul-Marked and Fate's Call.

Comment: This question seems to be primarily opinion based.  Any champion can be good played correctly, implying that this is asking for personal favorites.

Comment: @Ataxia there are definitly champs that have synergies with kalista and champs that would make absolutly nonsense to be soulboumd with (soraka,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all from theory-crafting the champion so we will need to see what comes out of actual play, however there are two main interactions with the support.

Firstly we have **Soul Marked**

> Soul-Marked - Passive: If Kalista and her Oathsworn ally attack the same target within 1.5 seconds of each other, the target will take additional magic damage equal to a percentage of their maximum health. This effect cannot occur on the same target for 8 seconds. Damage is capped against minions and monsters.

This generates extra poke each time Kalista and the support both attack the same target

The obvious point here is that a ranged support would be excellent as you can stack together your poke on the same target. For a melee support this particular passive will be less impressive although it will still help on all-ins.

Secondly we have **Fate's Call**

> During Fate's Call, Kalista's Oathsworn can right-click a target location to dash there, stopping at the first enemy hit, knocking up all surrounding enemies and landing themselves at their maximum attack range from the target.

Fate's Call disables the support's abilities for 4 seconds, so they will probably want to wait until near the end of the 4 seconds before going on. This will place them on top of the enemy team so you now want champions that can take advantage of this. Obvious choices are:

Morgana, this seems like it should be a really strong combination. You have the range to benefit from the poke passive, while at the same time having an ultimate that benefits from being in the middle of the enemy team. Additionally the knock-up will make it harder for them to avoid the stun at the end of the ultimate.

Janna, flash+ulti will throw the enemy team in all directions and some of them into your team to be picked off.

For both of these though the fact that you land at your maximum attack range weakens the combo considerably though, it gets you close but it may not get you close enough. On the other hand however it does make it less "all or nothing".

Leona, she can land her stun at close range and save Zenith Blade to follow anyone who flashes or uses an escape.

Amumu, similar to Leona, in the middle of their team lets you land an awesome ultimate and you can also follow a fleeing enemy with bandage toss.

There are a number of other champions that offer similar abilities too, Thresh's Box, Wukong's ultimate, Alistar's, knock up. Essentially any champion that thrives on being in close to the enemy team and that is able to lay down the pain.

One interesting possibility here is that if you have a melee support then you have already sacrificed the Soul Marked passive for poking (although it will help on an all-in). In that situation it might even make sense to form the bond with something like a Jungling Amumu. Use your ultimate to pull Amumu in then throw him at the enemy laners, he can then Curse of the Sad Mummy and follow any that get away using Bandage Toss.

Comment: its kind of a dilema: pick melee = you can land good ults
// pick ranged = high poke.

Comment: Yes, and I think from my analysis above that for the most part you will choose one or the other. Thresh being an obvious case that can benefit from both.

Comment: I feel Leona and other support with CC will be more useful Oathsworn since the knock back on `Fate's Call` is at attack range, melee champions won't go far away if you hit the a ranged champion. A bit restricting per se, that ability would be much more useful with a fixed range for the knock back. Also Leo's Z Blade makes the passive interesting, poke in, retreat, poke in... which is usually what you do anyway with Leo.

Comment: From what you state, Morgana may be nice - poke works, and at Fate's call you jump in the middle, pull your ultimate and Zhonya's.

Comment: @Peteris Yes, I meant to add Morgana but forgot. However I've also added a section on the fact that you end up at max attack range, which will weaken the combination for both Morgana and for Janna.

Comment: I think you're misreading the ability :`knocking up all surrounding enemies and landing themselves at their maximum attack range from the target.` Which means the other enemies (champs and minions) around the hit target gets knock back away up to their attack range. Rereading it that means you could knock back the adc by hitting an enemy minion.

Comment: I think annie would make a great choice.
long range auto attack plus once close to them, ulti with stun

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say thresh , mainly cause they can do the poke comp bot , Their combo's are based on mechanics just like morg + jinx comp

Answer (score -1):

I think is Bliz, when Bliz pull a enemy's adc, Kalista is able to hide some unsteadily attack, and they hardly to attack different target when this enemy is so close.

Of cours, player need to pay attention to other control ability from enemy's support.

Otherwise, Thresh is also good. All the attack nearly on Thresh, and enemy's adc is hard to runaway.

If you have good communicate with your supp, and your R is quite useful them others. You can chose Leona.